# MySQL uses index for a query but on adding another attribute, it does not use index?

Tags: mysql

While debugging to find the cause of slow updates (table has 54545371 rows), I tried:

```
explain UPDATE CellTable1015 SET value = (value * 1) WHERE entityId = 1 AND attributeId in (22, 3);

+----+-------------+---------------+------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+-------------+---------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table         | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref         | rows    | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+-------------+---------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | UPDATE      | CellTable1015 | NULL       | range | ea_ix,eal_ix  | eal_ix | 18      | const,const | 4930829 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+-------------+---------+----------+-------------+
```

Under the `key` column, you can see that a key is used `eal_ix`.
But when I try exactly the same query when adding a third attributeId `attributeId in (22, 3, 2)`, no key is used.

```
explain UPDATE CellTable1015 SET value = (value * 1) WHERE entityId = 1 AND attributeId in (22, 3, 2);
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table         | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | UPDATE      | CellTable1015 | NULL       | ALL  | ea_ix,eal_ix  | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 54545371 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
```

The indexes structure is:

```
show index from CellTable1015;
+---------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table         | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+---------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| CellTable1015 |          1 | ea_ix    |            1 | entityId    | A         |       54947 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| CellTable1015 |          1 | ea_ix    |            2 | attributeId | A         |       87755 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| CellTable1015 |          1 | eal_ix   |            1 | entityId    | A         |       61210 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| CellTable1015 |          1 | eal_ix   |            2 | attributeId | A         |       86116 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| CellTable1015 |          1 | eal_ix   |            3 | loc         | A         |      145572 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+---------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

**Few problems:**
1. Why would MySQL not use an index for the second query?
2. For the first query, MySQL is actually supposed to use the `ea_ix` index instead of the `eal_ix` index. Because `eal_ix` is created for a different query where there is an extra `AND loc=2` condition. Whereas `ea_ix` is a covering index created for `attributeId` and `entityId` **(this question is different from the one linked as a duplicate)**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySql refuses to use index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19773817/mysql-refuses-to-use-index)

Comment: update  your question and add .. the index  structure too

Comment: Updated. Another anomaly I encountered is that I altered the query to be something like `for(Integer attr: attributeIDs) {UPDATE CellTable1015 SET value = (value * 1) WHERE entityId = 1 AND attributeId=attr;}` so that it would use the indexes. It took 6.5 hours to update. Oddly, when I had used `attributeId IN(22,3,2)`, the update took just 5 hours. Are these bugs in MySQL? Worth reporting?